# Chance of bigger sized particle?

Tags: particles

What I want is there to be a particle emitter which emits random sizes but also has a small chance of getting a really big particle. Is this possible? I don't mind if it's integrated, an addon, nodes, scripts or whatever.

Comment: can it be on one spot ? or the position also has to be random ?

Comment: @Chebhou the position does not have to be random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use texture to control the size of the particles as follows : 
 - add a texture to the particle system

[image]

- in the texture tab change the influence to **size**

[image]

here is the result :

[image]

white regions -> full size particle
gray region -> small particles

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. A single object is not limited to one particle system. Add a second one for the really big particles and turn down the emission number.

Comment: This is correct but the other one used one particle system and added more detail/worked harder on their answer

Comment: I just found a much better way to do this. In the particle settings, under Render, select Group and then simply activate the "Use Count" box. It will then let you choose the ratio between the different particles.